# Cannot read special character in sagemaker

Tags: r, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I'm using the R Kernel in Sagemaker. I'm using this code:

```
prueba <-s3_read('s3://prueba/ejemplotildes.csv',  read.csv2, encoding='Latin-1')
head(prueba)
```

And the results bring the data without special latin chars like: á, é, í, ó, so a word that must to be like "opción" comes "opcin".

Do you know how can I bring my data exactly like the original?

Comment: indent your code to make it more readable (I tried to do it for you but it didn't appear to work for me..)

Comment: El código completo es:                                                                        
library(reticulate) 
sagemaker <- import('sagemaker')
session <- sagemaker$Session() 
bucket <- session$default_bucket()
role_arn <- sagemaker$get_execution_role()